# What can be the time complexity of below algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of **Binary to Decimal Conversion** ?

I think If there are K bits in a binary number, then TC would be **O(K)**, but, as we always tend to go for N bits in a binary number, then TC would be **O(N)**.

**How i got this** ,as i think like how many digits a decimal number would include to represent **N bit binary numbers.**

Then, it is 10^k - 1 = 2^N - 1 => K = N Log2 base10 => which gives **TC = O(N)**.

Can someone clarify this ?

Also, Is there is any chance to reduce this Time complexity ?

Comment: [Possibly of interest](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00864293v2/document).

Comment: What is the difference between K and N? Those are just letters, and are meaningless

Comment: @cricket_007 , K represents total number of bits. N is the count, If bits approach for N in worst case.

Comment: Personally, total number means "count" to me

Comment: @cricket_007, yes that's it .

Answer (score 1):

1. 10^k - 1 = 2^N - 1

Starting point.

2. K = N Log2 base10

-1 was present both left and right, so we added 1. we have:

10^k = 2^N now.

To get K from 10^k, we put both left and right into log of base 10. Since logarithm is the power you need to put the base to get the parameter, log(10^k) of base 10 will yield K. On the other hand, N Log2 base10 is the value we reach because of the logarithmization.

3. Since K, the number of bits is the complexity, the complexity is directly related to N Log2 base 10, which is N multiplied by a positive scalar. If N is assumed to be infinite, the scalar will not mean much of a difference analytically, therefore, we can simplify N Log2 base 10 to O(N)

Comment: Thanks, but i am not getting this => https://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs1104/BuildingBlocks/Chapter4.021.html

Comment: @Willturner, since I understand the situation, it is difficult for me to detect the part you do not understand. If you could ask concrete questions regarding my answer, I would happily help.

Answer (score 0):

A decimal digit can represent log(10)/log(2) binary digits, approximately 3.22.  But you want binary to decimal, so assume you need 4 bits per decimal digit. In any event, your output size is O(N) where N is your input size.

Now, that tells you very little about the time complexity of the unstated algorithm.

For small N, we can just do a table look up for O(1), but what about when N is large, e.g. 10^6?

A naive algorithm will process one bit of input at a time, doing a multiply/add on the output decimal. That's O(N) on the input, with each step costing O(N) because that's the cost to shift/add on the output. So O(N^2) is your time complexity.

Comment: Your N is the bit count, his x is the number of N bits, thus the log(x) term. Without seeing the algorithm, it's hard to guess at what the inner loop step is (is it really constant time for an arbitrary size N?)